# Check and increase the quantity of characters inside a cell using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify a cell inside a dataframe on panda but I am having a few quantity of problems:

For example, if I read a string with lower quantity of 4 digits, I need to increase '000'

```
travel_data['b'] = travel_data['b'].astype(str)
            travel_data['b'] = np.where(travel_data['b'].str.len() < 4, '000' + str(travel_data['b']), str(travel_data['b']))
```

But on this is not working, do you have any other idea?

Raphael

Comment: You can just do `travel_date['b'].str.zfill(4)` to achieve this

Comment: @EdChum Why don't you post these comments as solutions?

Comment: @TedPetrou because sometimes, and in fact a lot of the time, the problem is ill-defined or the question is not fully representative of the real problem. The number of times I post an answer and then get drip-fed more pertinent info that significantly changes the question is mind-numbing so I sometimes prefer to post a quick comment to see if that is sufficient. I don't like wasting time posting an answer only to be told, it doesn't work, then it becomes a ping-pong game of more info, try updated ans, a little more info, try again etc.. I'm a bit jaded to be honest with SO

Comment: @EdChum we love you :-) . Also Ted, this is a post on meta SO that basically suggests if you encounter this kind of comments and you fill the need for an answer, then you just should take the aspirational comment and post the answer.

Comment: @EdChum it did not worked, any other idea?

Comment: did you try assigning the result back? `travel_date['b'] = travel_date['b'].str.zfill(4)` otherwise, usual requests, raw data, code etc...

Comment: @EdChum I need to meet the condition similar with my question. Not only input four zeros. I tried inside np.where

Comment: OK, try `travel_data['b'] = np.where(travel_data['b'].str.len() < 4, '000' + travel_data['b'], travel_data['b'])` or more pandas like: `travel_data['b'] = travel_data['b'].where(travel_data['b'].str.len() >= 4, '000' + travel_data['b'])`

Comment: @EdChum I tried this on the first moment bit ot did not work too.